# 443 8443 iptable redirection

Tags: iptables, ssl, ufw, tomcat, https

Want to redirect 443 to tomcat 8443:

```
sudo iptables -t nat -n -L PREROUTING --line-numbers

num  target     prot opt source               destination
1    DOCKER     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ADDRTYPE match dst-type LOCAL
2    REDIRECT   tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:80 redir ports 8080
3    REDIRECT   tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:443 redir ports 8443

sudo ufw status

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
80/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere
8080/tcp                   ALLOW       Anywhere
8443/tcp                   ALLOW       Anywhere
443/tcp                    ALLOW       Anywhere
```

I can access https://lo.con.com:8443 but not https://lo.con.com.

**Access http is directing me correctly to 8080.**